# What I have to chance in my code to use the first SQL and not the first?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

What I have to chance in my code to use the first SQL and not the first?
Can someone help me please?

```
       //return supplies
            SELECT * FROM suppliers WHERE id=$id

        //return all suppliers itens
  SELECT
    suppliers.*,
    third_party_services.name as servicename
FROM
    suppliers
INNER JOIN
    suppliers_services
ON
    suppliers.id = suppliers_services.supplier_id
LEFT JOIN
    third_party_services
ON
    suppliers_services.id = third_party_services.id
WHERE
    suppliers_services.supplier_id = $id
```

I'm using an ajax to show all data into a modal
the ajax point to this .php

```
if(!empty($_POST)){
    if (isset($_POST['id']) && $_POST['id'] > 0){
        $id=$_POST['id'];
        GetSuppliersView();
    }
}
function GetSuppliersView() {
    global $db;
    global $id;
    try{
        $query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM suppliers WHERE id=$id");
        $row=$query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 
        $result['success'] = true;
        $result['result'] = $row;
        echo json_encode($result);
    return true;
    } catch (PDOException $pe) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

and this is the ajax code

```
$('.itemview').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#viewname").empty();
    $("#viewsuppliersocialname").val("");
    $("#viewsupplierfantasyname").val("");
    $("#viewsuppliercnpj").val("");
    $("#viewsuppliercontact").val("");
    $("#viewsupplieraddress").val("");
    $("#viewsupplierphone1").val("");
    $("#viewsupplierphone2").val("");
    $("#viewsupplierphone3").val("");
    $("#viewsupplieremail1").val("");
    $("#viewsupplieremail2").val("");
    $("#viewpaymentmethods").val("");
    var uid = $(this).data('id');
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "resources/controllers/get.php",
        data: 'id='+uid,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            if (data.success) {
                $('#viewname').append(data.result.name);
                $('#viewsuppliersocialname').val(data.result.social_name);
                $('#viewsupplierfantasyname').val(data.result.fantasy_name);
                $('#viewsuppliercnpj').val(data.result.cnpj);
                $('#viewsuppliercontact').val(data.result.contact);
                $('#viewsupplieraddress').val(data.result.address);
                $('#viewsupplierphone1').val(data.result.phone1);
                $('#viewsupplierphone2').val(data.result.phone2);
                $('#viewsupplierphone3').val(data.result.phone3);
                $('#viewsupplieremail1').val(data.result.email1);
                $('#viewsupplieremail2').val(data.result.email2);
                $("#viewpaymentmethods").val(data.result.paymenttype).change();
                $("#MethodView").modal('show');
            } else {

            }
        }
    });
});
```

Can someone help me please to do this?

Comment: what's the problem with  `JOIN` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    SELECT
    suppliers.*,
    third_party_services.name as servicename
FROM
    suppliers
INNER JOIN
    suppliers_services
ON
    suppliers.id = suppliers_services.supplier_id
LEFT JOIN
    third_party_services
ON
    suppliers_services.id = third_party_services.id
WHERE
    suppliers_services.supplier_id = $id
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do multiple JOINS and it just resolves left to right:

```
SELECT
    suppliers.*,
    suppliers_services.*,
    third_party_services.*
FROM
    suppliers
INNER JOIN
    suppliers_services
ON
    suppliers.id = suppliers_services.supplier_id
LEFT JOIN
    third_party_services
ON
    suppliers_services.id = third_party_services.id
WHERE
    supplier.id = $id
```

Comment: Looking at some corner-case behavior:

Clearly you want to produce a row even if "third_party_services" with $id doesn't exist because you do the left join. This still covers that case. In the event that $id doesn't hit something in "suppliers_services" where "supplier_id=$id", your old query would not produce a row, and it still doesn't because we do an inner join (meaning if it didn't show up in "suppliers_services" it doesn't produce a row, even though that supplier might exist).

Comment: It works with this: `SELECT
    suppliers.*,
    suppliers_services.*,
    third_party_services.*
FROM
    suppliers
INNER JOIN
    suppliers_services
ON
    suppliers.id = suppliers_services.supplier_id
LEFT JOIN
    third_party_services
ON
    suppliers_services.id = third_party_services.id
WHERE
    suppliers_services.supplier_id = 154` but how can I work with it using my code?

Comment: I updated main post, how can I work with it ? I must show all suppliers information and all services